# John Resigs micro templating engine, question of how to handle selects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templating

I've a template that looks like so:

```
<script type="text/html" id="TemplateEdit">

    <td>
        <input type="hidden" value="<#= item.ID #>" id="Edit.ID" name="Edit.ID" />
        <select id="Edit_ClientID" name="Edit.ClientID">
            <option value="1">test</option>
            <option value="2">test 2</option>
            <option value="3">test 3</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select id="Edit_Frequency" name="Edit.Frequency">
            <option value="1">Daily</option>
            <option value="2">Weekly</option>
            <option value="3">Fortnightly</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</script>
```

In the "item" object that I'm passing in, it has some properties such as item.ClientID, and item.Frequency.

And a generic function handles sucking in the template and injecting it:

```
var template = tmpl(editTemplate, { item: data }); // this runs jresig's template code
domEle.append(template); //append the results in
```

Theoretically, after this code is run I could do something like:

```
$("#Edit_ClientID").val(data.ClientID);
```

However I don't want to burden  this templating function with code specific for this templating exercise. This particular function handles templating for the entire site and I need to keep it generic.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write normal javascript in there, so if I understand your question correctly, you can just do something like this:

```
<script type="text/html" id="TemplateEdit">

    <td>
        <input type="hidden" value="<#= item.ID #>" id="Edit.ID" name="Edit.ID" />
        <select id="Edit_ClientID" name="Edit.ClientID">
            <option value="1" <# if(data.ClientID == 1){ #> selected <# } #>>test</option>
            <option value="2"<# if(data.ClientID == 2){ #> selected <# } #>>test 2</option>
            <option value="3"<# if(data.ClientID == 3){ #> selected <# } #>>test 3</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select id="Edit_Frequency" name="Edit.Frequency">
            <option value="1">Daily</option>
            <option value="2">Weekly</option>
            <option value="3">Fortnightly</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</script>
```

For executable javascript, use <# #>, rather than <#= #>

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass the entire list of <Options> as a template parameter? Not necesarily the most elegant... but it would avoid adding conditional logic to the template (ie. "is this item the currently selected item? Yes output "selected", no output nothing).